# How to share mp3 files from Google Drive with javascript with credentials for CORS or API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, cors

I have different mp3 files stored in Google Drive and with javascript I play them. First I used the following code:

```
var audio1 = new Audio("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id='id'");
```

But then I suddenly got the warning message of cors policy no 'access-control-allow-origin' and suddenly the audio files did not work anymore with a get 403 error. Then I used Google API with the following code:

```
var audio1 = new Audio("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'id'?alt=media&key='key'&v=.mp3");
```

Someone this does also not work. The audio stops playing suddenly. I receive a get 403 error about the files. Occasionally I even get the message of too many requests. I read somewhere that I should put the credentials in the http header. However it is not possible to access the http header in the prototyping program I'm working with.

Does someone know how to play different mp3 files in repeat without facing any credentials problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Google Drive API allows you to create apps that leverage Google Drive cloud storage. You can develop applications that integrate with Google Drive, and create robust functionality in your application using Google Drive API.

Google drive API is not intended for use as a file server. Its simply a file storage system. What you are trying to do is not going to work.

You should look at storing the files on your own file server.  You could also check [Google cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) if your looking for something on googles cloud servers.